# is it possible to create an Object in javascript from looping data in array?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, data-conversion

just like the title said. i want to create a new object from data inside array below:
the name of the object is the first and last name.

```js
//this is the input
arrayToObject([['Christ', 'Evans', 'Male'], ['Robert', 'Downey', 'Male']]);

//this is output that i want

// 1. Christ Evans:
// { firstName: 'Christ',
//   lastName: 'Evans',
//   gender: 'Male',

// 2. Robert Downey:
// { firstName: 'Robert',
//   lastName: 'Downey',
//   gender: 'Male',


// this is code that i write
function arrayToObject(arr) {
  
  let ObjName=""
  for (let i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
    
  
      let firstName=arr[i][0]
      let lastName=arr[i][1]
      let ObjName=firstName.concat(' ',lastName)
      let gender=arr[1][2]

      ObjName = { // idk how to make the object.
          'firstName':firstName,
          'lastName':lastName,
          'gender':gender,
          
      }
  }
  
}
```

im struggling in the part where i can declare the object.

Comment: I suppose you want an array of objects?

Comment: `let objectFromArray = array.map(el=>({firstName : el[0], lastName:el[1], gender : el[2]}))`

Comment: You want the name of the variable be 'Christ Evans'? Why?

Comment: The output that you want isn't an object, it's some text followed by an object. Or do you want something like `{'Christ Evans':{firstName:'Christ',...},'Robert Downey': {...}}`.

Comment: please add how the result should look like. do you want an array of objects? or just a single object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could take a nested approach with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and map the properties with a keys array.

```js
var data = [['Christ', 'Evans', 'Male'], ['Robert', 'Downey', 'Male']],
    keys = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'gender'],
    result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(a => [
        a.slice(0, 2).join(' '),
        Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, i) => [k, a[i]]))
    ]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what is wrong with it?

Comment: No idea: somebody is on a downvote streak for no reason... :/ your answer is just as legit :)

Comment: no downvote from me, but why not just `.map` function?

Comment: i get it now he would to have something like dynamic variable names

Comment: "*i want to create **a new object** from data inside array below: **the name of the object is the first and last name.***" [emph: me]

Answer (score -1):

I would suppose you want an array of objects with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Christ",
    "lastName": "Evans",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Robert",
    "lastName": "Downey",
    "gender": "Male"
  }
]
```

If that's the case, you can simply use `Array.prototype.map`, and in the callback you simply use array destructuring to unpack the second level array into `firstName`, `lastName` and `gender`:

```js
function arrayToObject(arr) {
  return arr.map((entry) => {
    const [firstName, lastName, gender] = entry;
    return {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      gender
    };
  });
}

const a = arrayToObject([['Christ', 'Evans', 'Male'], ['Robert', 'Downey', 'Male']]);
console.log(a);
```